# How we can call multiple blocks in a single controller?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, admin-controller

Is there a way to call multiple blocks in a single controller in Magento 2?
The below code only populate the single grid but I want it to return two blocks.

```
public function execute()
    {
        /* @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw /
        $resultRaw = $this->_resultRawFactory->create();
        return $resultRaw->setContents(
            $this->_layoutFactory->create()->createBlock(
                \Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Grid::class,
                'mytestgrid'
            )->toHtml()
        );
    }
```

Comment: You have to use view model concept of Magento or with the help of layout you can call multiple blocks.

Comment: @Ankit I am creating _prepareColumn() which creates a grid and I want to call it from a controller using rawFactory. So I don't want to call any method from a block.

Comment: https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-getchildhtml/#:~:text=05%2F07%2F2021%202%20Mins,for%20your%20page%20is%20created.